# Is there a way to only edit one file for my menu?

Tags: html, css, menu

I have a menu on my html website, and it works just fine, except that whenever I change one link, I have to go through all the files and change that link on every file. Is there a way to have it so I only have to change one link?

I know you can reference a css stylesheet with the link element, so would it be possible to do the same with html? That way, I could reference that file in all my pages for the menu, and if I wanted to edit the menu, I would only have to edit that referenced file.

Comment: Add screenshot  or minimal example or html | css

Comment: I cant really provide a screenshot, im just wondering if there is some code that will allow me to reference a seperate html document, like you can do with css documents. 

Is there something like 
```<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path">```
but for html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use jquery for make dynamic link.
You can use this jquery code in a js file and attach that in all of your pages.
When you need to change the link, you should only change the link in js file.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".your-tag-class").attr("href", "https://www.your-link.com/");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: How would I go about using that? My current menu, has a bunch of `<a href>`. what would I replace them with, and where would I put them in the js document?

I have this currently
`
<div class="menuBox">
  <p class="menuBoxTitle">Which area do you want to visit?</p>
  <a href="" class="area">About this Website</a>
  <a href="" class="area">School Projects</a>
  <a href="" class="area">Coding Projects</a>
</div>
`

Comment: You should add a class on your tag. (ex: <a href="" class="your-tag-class">...</a>)

Comment: Then create a js file (for example: scripts.js) and add that code in this file. At the last you should attach js file end of youe pages.

Comment: add this lines end of your pages before </body> tag: <script src="scripts.js"></script> <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Just remember you should add separate classes for each link to can change link for each tag.

Comment: I did all that, and I still cant get it to work. I added the class to my main document ```  <a href="" class="my-menu">About this Website</a>```, I added these link things to the main document also, ```<script src=".mainResources/mainMenuItems.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>```, and I also added this ```$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".my-menu").attr("href", "https://www.your-link.com/");
});
``` to the js file I made

Comment: I can get it to work by adding the script located in my js file to my html file... and I double checked that the path was correct, so the code works, I just cant get it to work if it is in another file...

Comment: Yes you can first test this code into your file and when it worked move that to a js file and attach to all of your pages.

Comment: When I moved it to the js file, it stopped working. I have the <script src=".mainResources/mainMenuItems.js"></script>
path correct.

Comment: Please make sure the jquery file is loaded. view page source and click on the link.

Comment: both of the links work in the source (the jsquery, and the js document I created)

Comment: If your project is online please share your link to help you better. else please check this page [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_dom_attr_set)

Comment: I just put my project online, and the url is http://trm.ddns.net/beta/index.html. If you hover over the about this website, it will not point anywhere even though it has the correct class.

Comment: Thanks. please do this steps to resolve problem: 1. move jquery link top of other js files. 2. remove <script> and </script> tag from mainMenuItems.js file.

Comment: That works!! Thanks. One more question though, is there any way I can do the same thing but with the text that is displayed? (in the a href tag?)

Comment: Your welcome. Yes you can use this code to change your text: $(".my-menu").text("your-new-text");

Comment: Yes that works!! One more question, Is there a way so the file paths (in the js documents) all originate from one file location? So I can use the same paths (ex. ../index.html) even when I am like 3 folders back (so I would have to do ../../../index.html)? Like I would want it so the paths all originate from the js document, or a preset location instead of the html document (which could be anywhere...)

Comment: I have no idea for that. But the best way is place all your js files in js folder, css files in css folder and all of html files in root. In this situation all of your links are same.